# RMI with Robot class

Tags: java, awt, rmi, awtrobot

### Problem:

If we remotely (Remote Method Invocation application) set the co-ordinates of mouse of any other system using its IP for an infinite time then,
control remains there for infinite time and our application hangs until the server of that system falls.

### Question

Is there any solution, to lock mouse of remote system for infinite time and control returns back to root system - using Remote Method Invocation (Java)?

```
try{Robot r = new Robot();
while(true){
r.mouseMove(0,0);
}
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: WOW, while(true){r.mouseMove(0,0);} this is just disaster, why do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

of course your system will hang, if not it's a surprise, first set the mouse location by mouseMove(0,0), then you need to add mouse hook listener, to remove again the mouse cursor to 0,0 (NOT IN WHILE LOOP!), and just after the task(if any), remove the listener

Comment: will you please specify it more,actually i am not exactly getting you,any other more general way??
I have tried sleep method to lock mouse for a perticular time but not getting how to prevent application from hanging up...

Comment: well this is not okay to set the mouse location in a while loop again and again, at the first you set it to location 0 and 0, then DO NOT set the location for n times in a while loop, it's bad

Comment: if you really need to keep mouse at 0, and 0, after setting the location to 0 and 0, add a mouseActionListener to your application, and for any mouse movement then set it to 0 and 0

Comment: @AkshayShrivas Hope I could tell you my mean, please response in order of either success or failure :D